# Request header field x-access-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: jwt, access-token

I'm using jsonwebtoken for authentication for a movie database. I'm calling the API of the movie database(tmdb) from my client side. The registration and login are handled by the server side. I've configured my client side to get the movies using the API. After following the server-side tutorial for backend [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRPwKuIz8Os&list=PL3vQyqzqjZ637sWpKvniMCxdqZhnMJC1d&index=9), I'm able to store the token and login. But as soon as I login, the API requests are all gone. Only the token remains. After I logout, all the API requests for my app comes back (i.e) my front-end for movies. As soon as I login, the API requests for movie, tv shows are gone stating

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=###. Request header field x-access-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Looks like a CORS problem. If it's not properly handled by the server, you could consider JSONP as the return type.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this ?